# Rails 4 multidomain application with locale set for each domain i18n locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

In a Rails 4 multidomain app, I would need a set of locale files for 4 languages for each domain (3 domains total).

Some of the translations overlap between the domains but some of them are very specific, so I am thinking about a structure that would go somewhat like this:

```
config/locales/en.yml ..fr.yml ..de.yml ..it.yml  #is picked up by all domains
config/locales/domain1/en.yml ..fr.yml ..de.yml ..it.yml  #is picked up by domain 1
config/locales/domain2/en.yml ..fr.yml ..de.yml ..it.yml  #is picked up by domain 2
config/locales/domain3/en.yml ..fr.yml ..de.yml ..it.yml  #is picked up by domain 3
```

Is this possible in Rails 4? And if so what would be the best way to go about this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `config/application` you would have:

```
some_domain = Rails.root.basename.to_s # this will give us "myapp.com" if the app is in "/var/www/myapp.com"
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', some_domain, '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
```

this will load only the required files and *should* overwrite any duplicate keys with the later data, but i haven't tested that bit.

Comment: Basename will only return the Rails app name not the domain name.

Comment: Domain name would be returned by `request.domain` but it is of course not available in `application.rb` at initialization time.

Comment: I will need to take a different approach, since domain will always be only available when a request is made ... it is a chicken egg problem

Comment: Also Note: this is a multidomain app serving 3 different domain names.

Comment: so you've got a single app running once for the 3 domains? you might want to consider deploying to different paths so that you can precompile things like this in advance. that's what i did with these three: http://www.absave.com http://www.labsave.com http://www.biosave.com

Comment: yeah I got one app to rule them all. The sites are very similar thus I find it much easier to do it that way, one codebase etc.

Comment: yep, the way i'm suggesting is one app too, you just deploy to 3 different directories which has other advantages such as precompiling assets for just that domain etc.

Comment: 1 app, 1 server, 3 paths, 3 processes.

Comment: you got any pointers on how to do the deployment to different paths. When I say webserver I mean `unicorn` instances.

Comment: just set up 3 different capistrano deploy environments

Answer (score 1):

Please try with `i18n-active_record`.in that all the `locales` we can store it in `database`.

in this gem they are using `translation` model with no relation,in your case you could create relation between `relation` and `domain`,then you could store all locales with `domain` based when getting locales you could overwrite default gem method.

==> your keys should contain use domain name for find the domain or you can use some other way to get the domain name like in `thread` or `env` you can save your value.

# my guess key should be login-label-test.com
  domain =  Domain.where(:name => namespace.split("-").last).first

inside gem where ever they are finding `translation` just overwrite that method please try it.

i am not sure please try once like that

first migrate your `locale` file to `db`

```
require 'yaml'

namespace :locale do
 desc "Copy translations from yml yo db. Non-overwriting."
  task :yml_to_db, [:environment, :locale,:domain] => :environment do |t, args|
    info = YAML::load(IO.read("#{Rails.root}/config/locales/#{args[:locale]}-#{args[:domain]}.yml"))
    domain = Domain.where(:name => args[:domain]).first
    info["#{args[:locale]}"].each do |key, value|
    translation = domain.translations.where(:key => key)
    domain.translations.create!(:key => key, :value => value, :locale => args[:locale]) if translation.blank?
   end
  end
 end
```

i have tried to overwrite one method in gem :

```
require 'active_record'

  module I18n
   module Backend
   class ActiveRecord
    class Translation < ::ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :domain

    TRUTHY_CHAR = "\001"
    FALSY_CHAR = "\002"

    self.table_name = 'translations'

    serialize :value
    serialize :interpolations, Array

      def lookup(keys, *separator)
        # in your keys should contain use domain name for find the domain or you can use some other way to get the domain name like in thread or env you can save your value.

        column_name = connection.quote_column_name('key')
        keys = Array(keys).map! { |key| key.to_s }

        unless separator.empty?
          warn "[DEPRECATION] Giving a separator to Translation.lookup is deprecated. " <<
            "You can change the internal separator by overwriting FLATTEN_SEPARATOR."
        end

        namespace = "#{keys.last}#{I18n::Backend::Flatten::FLATTEN_SEPARATOR}%"
        # my guess key should be login-label-test.com
        domain =  Domain.where(:name => namespace.split("-").last).first
        where("#{column_name} IN (?) OR #{column_name} LIKE ?", keys, namespace).where(:id => domain.id)
       end
   end
  end
 end
```

Please try like this.

Comment: yes this could be an approach but I find it overly complicated. I'd like to keep my translations in .yml files for easy access and easy edit. So this is not an approach I want to take.