# Rails4 one codebase multiple domains each with default locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, locale, rails-i18n

I have this setup with rails 4, i18n, git, heroku:

- myapp-hu-stage.herokuapp.com
- myapp-hu-live.herokuapp.com with the domain myapp.hu

Currently this is Hungarian only. In config/initializers/i18n.rb I have:

```
Rails.application.config.i18n.default_locale = :hu
```

I would like to have other sites with other default languages with the same codebase but different domain and DB. For example:

UK - English en_GB

- myapp-uk-stage.herokuapp.com
- myapp-uk-live.herokuapp.com with the domain myapp.co.uk (second level domain! setting locale from domain wont work - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-domain-name)

USA - English en_US

- myapp-us-stage.herokuapp.com
- myapp-us-live.herokuapp.com with the domain myapp.com

SPAIN - Spanish

- myapp-es-stage.herokuapp.com
- myapp-es-live.herokuapp.com with the domain myapp.es

etc...

I have been searching for at least a day now but found only two realated:

- [Rails 4 multidomain application with locale set for each domain i18n locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211925/rails-4-multidomain-application-with-locale-set-for-each-domain-i18n-locale) - here I am not sure about the answer
- https://medium.com/unexpected-token/making-your-website-multi-regional-using-top-level-domains-cdbbdb951b65 - here I guess the author is having one DB whereas I need different DB per domain

So my question is exactly how and in which file(s) do I define one locale per domain?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

[set_locale](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-domain-name) should work. All you need is set:

> I18.locale = :(lang you want to use for the current request)

base on your conditions. So in your case, is sub-domain (not tld). For example:

```
def extract_locale_from_subdomain
  # get subdomain string (myapp-uk-stage.herokuapp.com return myapp-uk-stage)
  subdomain = request.host.split('.').first
  if subdomain == 'myapp-uk-stage'
    I18n.locale = :en
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Leonardo, thanks but I will use my own domain not the heroku subdomain. Or does this solution also work when the user arrives to www.my-app.co.uk ?

Comment: yea, why not =) "request.host" will return the host name as string, you can use simple if/then/else condition checking, to match your need. Remember, you should always have a 'else' at the end, to handle any un-expected case. (such as user access your server using IP address)

Comment: I see... And then I guess I can edit it like this, can I?

def extract_locale_from_domain
 domain = request.host
  if domain == 'myapp.co.uk'
    I18n.locale = :en
  else
    ...
  end
end

And how should my config/initializers/i18n.rb look like? Just comment out?

Comment: just keep config/initializers/i18n.rb there.